# Why my design is disturbing when zoom out

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating bootstrap design and when screen goes big it's making issue, actually I am a backend developer, but currently facing this issue

```
<section class="local-services" @if (isset($meta['eye']) && $meta['eye'] == 'off') style="display:none; " @endif >
    <div class="container somesection" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @if($meta['heading'])
                <div class="heading-panel text-center">
                    <h1><span class="heading-color" style="font-weight: 400;">{{ ($meta['heading'])??'' }} </span> </h1>
                    <br>
                    <span>{{ ($meta['sub_heading'])??'' }}</span>
                </div>
            @else
                <div class=" text-center">

                    <span>{{ ($meta['sub_heading'])??'' }}</span>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-6" style="width: 696px;height: 424px; z-index: 9">
                <img style="width: 696px;height: 424px;" src="{{url(($meta['image'])??'#')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3  " style="width: 696px;height: 424px;border: 2px solid black;transform: translate(-10%, 10%);padding: 92px;">
                {!! ($meta['description']) !!}
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <span class="right_text_read_more">Read More...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

It's a design
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sRjF.jpg)

I am expecting that code and Image should be in the same line
[What I exactly want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUDql.jpg)

Comment: `<div class="col col-sm-6" style="width: 696px;height: 424px; z-index: 9">` - messing with the column dimensions, by applying a fixed width & height via inline styles, is a really bad idea.

Comment: Actually, I just apply inline here to show more easily

Comment: Showing us stuff that is different from the real situation, isn't really that helpful. And neither is showing us your template code - you should rather provide a proper [mre] of the issue, based on the resulting HTML.

Comment: Its a whole section which is everything